# How to find custom catalog search in magento2?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, response

We checked the following url in `http://localhost/magento2/search/ajax/suggest/?q=tes&_=1545813701256`

In this url, how to customize the response from that url.

My file path: `app/code/Magento/Search/Controller/Ajax`

Comment: What do you mean by customize the response ? you want to rewrite that controller ?

Comment: We need to show some extra response data from that result